# opencv2.framework/opencv2(surf.o) duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, image-processing, uiimage

I am integrating opencv2.framework with my project. I did the following steps for completion.

1. Added opencv2.framework to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
2. Added libc++.dylib to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
3. Added following code to AppName-Prefix.pch file

   *#ifdef* __cplusplus
   *#import* "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
   *#endif*
4. Changed compiler default of 
   Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - Language -> C++ Language Dialect -> GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11]
                                         C++ Standard Library -> libc++ (LLVM C++ standard libray with C++ 11 support)

Still I am getting a link error which is saying

"opencv2.framework/opencv2(surf.o)
ld: 21 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7"

Can anyone help me on this?

**EDIT:**

My XCode version is 4.6, IOS SDK is 6.1 and deployment target is 4.3 (I tested with 5.0 also, but not working in that target too)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** github pull [request](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1771) which fixes this issue is now merged to OpenCV.

**Cause:** 
In OpenCV [source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/nonfree/src), there are two files named 1. surf.cpp and 2. surf.ocl.cpp which results in two surf.o object files for each architecture inside opencv framework library.

**Fix:** 
 In OpenCV source, apply patch from github pull [request](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1771)
and [Build](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation) OpenCV for iOS.

**See:** Use [lipo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578771/extract-object-o-files-from-an-iphone-static-library) on OpenCV to extract separate libs for each architecture ( armv7, armv7s and i386 ) and then use `ar -tv` to see two object files of same size with name surf.o

**I don't know:**  Only some XCode projects fails with the pre built OpenCV framework. I use Xcode 5.0 with OpenCV 2.4.6.1. Can this be fixed with some XCode build setting ?

Comment: @Kiran.. Thank you for the answer. I think there is some XCode build setting or something to fix this problem. I fixed the issue, but didn't remembering now. The post was added on 5 months ago. :)